# Alphanumeric array sorting with multiple values

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

Its simple like this. I need to sort an array with multiple values alphanumeric

this.tests = [

```
  {
    "title": "047 - Wunsc",
    "link": "47",
  },
  {
    "title": "014 - Expl",
    "link": "14",
  },
  {
    "title": "004 - Ausw",
    "link": "4",
  },
  {
    "title": "001 - Abhef",
    "link": "1",
  },
  {
    "title": "006 - Beurt",
    "link": "6",
  },
  {
    "title": "015 - Explo",
    "link": "15",
  },
  {
    "title": "029 - Physi",
    "link": "29",
  },
  {
    "title": "016 - Befra",
    "link": "16",
  }
]
```

This is what I've tried so far.

```
this.tests.sort(function (a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a.title) - parseFloat(b.title);
});

this.tests.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
```

But still getting no alphanumeric/natural sort

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: this.test != this.tests

Comment: (Also, please don't post a question and leave. Please be available for clarifications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this pattern just sort by string.

```js
var data = [{ title: "047 - Wunsc", link: "47" }, { title: "014 - Expl", link: "14" }, { title: "004 - Ausw", link: "4" }, { title: "001 - Abhef", link: "1" }, { title: "006 - Beurt", link: "6" }, { title: "015 - Explo", link: "15" }, { title: "029 - Physi", link: "29" }, { title: "016 - Befra", link: "16" }];

data.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you like to sort only by description part, you could slice the string.

```js
var data = [{ title: "047 - Wunsc", link: "47" }, { title: "014 - Expl", link: "14" }, { title: "004 - Ausw", link: "4" }, { title: "001 - Abhef", link: "1" }, { title: "006 - Beurt", link: "6" }, { title: "015 - Explo", link: "15" }, { title: "029 - Physi", link: "29" }, { title: "016 - Befra", link: "16" }];

data.sort((a, b) => a.title.slice(6).localeCompare(b.title.slice(6)));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It's already mentioned in the question (upd: the comment doesn't apply to the edited version of the answer)

Comment: @AndreyOzornin, for me, it looks like two sortings, one oafter the other.